# Assigning Different Markers in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am working on a project using **Google maps** and **Classic ASP**. The map has various locations which are pulled out of the DB and that is fine and works perfectly.

**What I want need to do is assign different markers depending on property type etc.**

I have searched and cannot find how to do as my javascript is not great. Any pointers would be gratefully received. I do need to use the following code, but tweaked.

**PS:** *I have taken the ASP delimiters out as code seemed to be trying to execute :-)*

```
var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
var center = null;
var map = null;
var currentPopup;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    bounds.extend(pt);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pt,
        icon: '../img/map/Bar.png',
        map: map
    });
    var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: info,
        maxWidth: 500
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        if (currentPopup != null) {
            currentPopup.close();
            currentPopup = null;
        }
        popup.open(map, marker);
        currentPopup = popup;
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
        map.panTo(center);
        currentPopup = null;
    });
}

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
        },
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    });
    sSQL = "select id, name, province, lat, lng, map_include, map_type from resort where (map_include = 'Playa Del Ingles' and live = 1) order by id asc"
    Set ors = cn.Execute(sSql)
    do while not ors.eof
    //loop does stuff here which I won't bore you about
    response.write "addMarker(" & lat & "," & lon & ",'<h4 style=""margin-bottom:10px"">" & name & "</h4><img class=""prop_img"" src=""../resorts/" & prop_id & "/1.jpg""><div style=""width:300;float:left""><strong>" & prop_type & "</strong><br />" & province & "<br /><a href=""../" & page_url & "/resort.asp?hid=" & prop_id & """>More Details</a></div>')" & VbCrLf & ";"
    ors.movenext
    loop
    center = bounds.getCenter();
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing alot of your code, I would change the addMarker method to include an 'icon' parameter, so change

```
function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
```

to

```
function addMarker(icon, lat, lng, info) {
```

Then change the 'icon' property from the new marker, change

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pt,
    icon: '../img/map/Bar.png',
    map: map
});
```

to

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pt,
    icon: icon,
    map: map
});
```

and lastly change the addMarker call

```
addMarker(" & lat & "," & lon & ", ...
```

to

```
addMarker(YourIconURLHere, " & lat & "," & lon & ", ...
```

You'd need to change the icon url based on the property (or the map_type I presume) you get from your SQL query.

Comment: Matthew thank you. You are a star!!! That works perfectly. Now as I am new here just working how to mark you up and say thanks :-)

Comment: No problem, thought I'd help someone out while waiting for an answer on my own problem. If somebody answered your question all you have to do is mark the answer.